# how do i merge these date rows to months?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-cleaning

i have a  multiple csv files dataframes for covid cases that looks like this:

```
    Region  active
Date        
2020-03-20  Tabuk   1
2020-03-21  Tabuk   1
2020-03-22  Tabuk   1
2020-03-23  Tabuk   1
2020-03-24  Tabuk   1
... ... ...
2021-02-04  Tabuk   8
2021-02-04  Tabuk   3
2021-02-04  Tabuk   34
2021-02-05  Tabuk   4
2021-02-05  Tabuk   34
```

and as you can see the dates are not sorted and they are messy besides not every month has the same number of days (it depends on cases recorded) .
so I wanna merge the date rows while adding the cases (active) rows for each month to have the sum cases for each month so the result looks like this:

```
    Region  active
Date        
march   Tabuk   56
april   Tabuk   89
may     Tabuk   150
june    Tabuk   34
july    Tabuk   65
... ... ...
```

how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First if necessary create `DatetimeIndex` and sorting:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index)

df = df.sort_index()
```

Aggregate `sum` with monh names generated by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df = df.groupby([df.index.strftime('%B'),'Region'],sort=False)['active'].sum().reset_index()
```

Or by [`DatetimeIndex.month_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.month_name.html):

```
df = df.groupby([df.index.month_name(),'Region'],sort=False)['active'].sum().reset_index()
```